# Can I install WSO2 EMM on Google App Engine?

Tags: wso2

Just wondering if I can install WSO2 on Google App Engine?

If not, was anyone successful using Hostgator VPS (either Snappy 500 or 1000)?

I just need to try it out so I am looking for a cost effective solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure abt it, better you try with min-requiremtns.

https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM100/Prerequisites

As far as i know, Linode or Rackspace much better than Hostgator..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start off with configuring the EMM pack in your local machine. Once its done you can find out what are the needed components in order to host it in a production server.